# Finding overlapping region between two ranges of integers

Tags: c#, range, .net-core, intersection

I am making a complex algorithm in C# in which one step is to compare 2 very large lists of ranges and finding out the overlapping region. I have tried a lot of ways to find them, but m not sure if I am covering all possibilities. Also my algo on this step is taking too long with huge lists.

**Example:**

**range 1 = 1-400**

**range 2 = 200-600**

So when I want to check overlap between these two ranges I should get the answer = 200.

Because total 200 numbers are overlapping between these two ranges. So this is how I want the answer, I want the exact number of integers that are overlapping between two ranges.

**Example of Lists:**

List1 : 1-400, 401-800, 801-1200 and so on...
List2 : 10240-10276, 10420  10456, 11646-11682 and so on...

Now I have to compare each range of list1 with each range of list2, and find out if a certain range of list1 overlaps with any of the range of list2 and if yes then what is the overlapping answer? These are just sample values for the purposes of understanding.

I only need a simple and most efficient/fast formula to find out the overlap answer between 2 ranges. I can manage the rest of the loop algorithm.

**Example formula** :

```
var OverlappingValue = FindOverlapping(range1.StartValue, range1.EndValue,range2.StartValue, range2.EndValue);
```

and if the two ranges are not overlapping at all, then function must return 0.

PS: I didn't post my code because it's really complicated with a lot of conditions, I only need one simple formula.

Comment: Can you just do 400-200?

Comment: if range2.start < range1.end then range1.end - range2.start

Comment: @OscarSiauw You also have to check if range1.start is before or after range2.end and if range2.end is before or after range1.end.

Comment: So? whats your solution?

Comment: There are 201 integers between 200 and 400 not 200 (or you need to explain how bounds are inclusive/exclusive)

Comment: There is an Intersect() function if you work with lists in your algorithm

Comment: Basically you need to check for the six cases if range2 is before range1, range2 is after range1, range2 covers range1, range2 is covered by range1, range2 covers the start of range1, or range 1 covers the start of range2.

Comment: @Sehnsucht yes u r right, there are 201 integers, my case in inclusive, I need one on one match checking.

Comment: `a simple and most efficient/fast formula` - a nice contradiction you have there :-)

Comment: [Merge Overlapping Intervals](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/) algorithm can give some leads.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If there is any overlapping range ; it must start from the max lower bound to the min upper bound so just use that "formula"
Then just get the number of item in that range by subtracting it's upper bound to it's lower one and add one (to be all inclusive)
Finally if that amount is negative it means that the range weren't overlapping so just get the max between that amount and 0 to handle that case

**Edit :** Oops C# not VB.Net

```
int FindOverlapping (int start1, int end1, int start2, int end2)
{
    return Math.Max (0, Math.Min (end1, end2) - Math.Max (start1, start2) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, u gave me exactly what i needed and perfect function with just one line and it totally make sense. Thanks again :)

Comment: this didn't work for me at all. I used ulong numbers.
start1: 5388080000200
end1: 5388080000299
start2: 2483090000000000
end2: 2483099999999999
Clearly those 2 ranges do not overlap at all, but the result is: 18444266371789551916 instead of 0

Comment: @Nick:  I just tried this in LINQpad (with long instead of int) and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    double adStart = 1.501;
    double adEnd = 21.83;
    double bdStart = 0.871;
    double bdEnd = 56.81;

    int aiStart = 21;
    int aiEnd = 35;
    int biStart = 29;
    int biEnd = 43;

    // 20.239
    double dOverlap = FindOverlapping((int)(adStart*1000), (int)(adEnd*1000), (int)(bdStart*1000), (int)(bdEnd*1000))/1000.0;

    // 6
    int iOverlap = FindOverlapping(aiStart, aiEnd, biStart, biEnd);

    // 0
    iOverlap = FindOverlapping(20, 25, 26, 30);

    // 0
    iOverlap = FindOverlapping(20, 25, 25, 30);
}

int FindOverlapping(int aStart, int aEnd, int bStart, int bEnd)
{
    int overlap = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(aStart, aEnd - aStart).Intersect(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(bStart, bEnd - bStart)).Count();

    return overlap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A one-liner formula to use would be this one.

Let's say you have 2 intervals:
(a1, a2) and (b1, b2)

Then the overlapping region would be: max{0, min{a2-b1, b2-a1}}

Comment: This is just wrong. If a1<b1 and a2>b2, your formula will return a value greater than the actual overlap. 
If your ranges overlap (a1<b2 & b1<a2), then the overlap is given by min(a2,b2) - max(a1,b1)